# Constraints to superview not working

Tags: swift, autolayout

I add a subView to a superview and I want to constrain the subview. But it does not do anything. The subview is added fullscreen over the superview. Please help me, what is going wrong?

This is my code:

```
  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    setupConstraints()
  }

  func setupConstraints(){   
    heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 80)
    bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view.superview!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 30)
    widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view.superview!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    view.superview!.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    view.addConstraint(heightConstraint!)
    view.addConstraint(widthConstraint!)
    view.addConstraint(bottomConstraint!)
  }
```

Comment: Why you dont just add constraints to your `view` instead of the `superview`?

Comment: This won't change a thing

Comment: instead of doing `view.superview!.addConstraint()`, have you tried to do `NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([heightConstraint, bottomConstraint, widthConstraint])`

Comment: Does not change anything :(

Comment: Not quite understand what your `bottomConstraint` mean, 500 is a big number, you might not even able to see the view at all.

Comment: It does not matter, what numbers I enter. It does not work. I had the 500 for testing =)

Comment: You might want to add the code about how you add your `view` to the `superview`

Comment: I didn't find the x constrainst in your code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your constraints are ambiguous (underdetermined). There is not enough information to know where to put your `view`.

There are four pieces of information that must be known:

```
* x position
* y position
* width
* height
```

Look at your constraints, and consider what each one determines:

```
heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 80)
```

That's height.

```
bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view.superview!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 30)
```

That's y position.

```
widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view.superview!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
```

That's width.

Ooops! What about x position?

Another problem with your code could be this line:

```
view.superview!.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
```

You remove `view.superview`'s automatically generated constraints by saying that — but you do not replace them by any new constraints. So it may be ambiguously configured too at this point (unless it already has a complete set of constraints we don't know about, but then in that case that line is unnecessary).

---

In my book, I provide code for some utility methods to help track down this kind of thing:

```
extension NSLayoutConstraint {
    class func reportAmbiguity (var v:UIView?) {
        if v == nil {
            v = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
        }
        for vv in v!.subviews as! [UIView] {
            println("\(vv) \(vv.hasAmbiguousLayout())")
            if vv.subviews.count > 0 {
                self.reportAmbiguity(vv)
            }
        }
    }
    class func listConstraints (var v:UIView?) {
        if v == nil {
            v = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
        }
        for vv in v!.subviews as! [UIView] {
            let arr1 = vv.constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis(.Horizontal)
            let arr2 = vv.constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis(.Vertical)
            NSLog("\n\n%@\nH: %@\nV:%@", vv, arr1, arr2);
            if vv.subviews.count > 0 {
                self.listConstraints(vv)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you run `NSLayoutConstraint.reportAmbiguity(view.superview!)`, preferably in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` at a time after your `view` has been injected into the view hierarchy, you will find that `view` reports as ambiguous. That's why you are not seeing what you expect.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. But it does not report any ambiguity for me

Comment: Well, you have to ask after layout has a chance to occur.  But you can readily see that they are ambiguous. What should the view's horizontal position be? You do not define it.

Comment: Added a whole bunch more info about this in my answer.

Comment: Trank you. Got it sorted out. Obvious but blind. Need to Check out your Book tho